# Why isnt this code in vhdl simulating anything?(testbench and design)

Tags: vhdl

```
--

library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity D_flip_flop is

port ( 

        D : in STD_LOGIC;
        Q : inout STD_LOGIC;
        Q_tonos : out STD_LOGIC;
        CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
        RST : in STD_LOGIC
        );

end D_flip_flop;

architecture Behavioral of D_flip_flop is

begin

process_flip_flip: process

begin

wait until CLK'EVENT AND CLK = '1';

if(RST='1') then

    Q <= '0';
    else 
    Q <= D;
    end if;
    Q_tonos <= not Q;

end process process_flip_flip;
end Behavioral;

-------------------------

--testbench

LIBRARY ieee;

USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;



ENTITY test_flip_flop IS

END test_flip_flop;

ARCHITECTURE tb OF test_flip_flop IS 



    COMPONENT D_flip_flop
    PORT(

         D : IN  std_logic;
         Q : INout  std_logic;
         Q_tonos : OUT  std_logic;
         CLK : IN  std_logic;
         RST : IN  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;



   signal D : std_logic ;

   signal CLK : std_logic ;

   signal RST : std_logic ;



   signal Q : std_logic;



   signal Q_tonos : std_logic;


   constant CLK_period : time := 10 ns;
   signal stopClk : boolean;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   dut: D_flip_flop PORT MAP (

          D => D,
          Q => Q,
          Q_tonos => Q_tonos,
          CLK => CLK,
          RST => RST
        );

   CLK_process :process

   begin

        while not stopClk loop

        CLK <= '0';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
        CLK <= '1';
        wait for CLK_period/2;
        end loop;
        wait;
   end process CLK_process;


   -- Stimulus process

   stim_proc: process
   begin        


      -- insert stimulus here 
        D <= '0';
        RST <= '1';
        wait for 100 ns;

        D <= '0';
        RST <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;

        D <= '1';
        RST <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;

        D <= '1';
        RST <= '0';
        wait for 100 ns;

        wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Comment: You haven't really described your problem.  What do you *want* this code to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: its supposed to be a d-flipflop in vhdl but when I simulate to see the diagrams in doesnt give me anything and I dont know whats wrong.. the clock doesnt work either and I dont know whats wrong with the code..

Comment: If the clock is not working, then please  reduce your code, so that , only the clock process and required signal declarations are left. Then the error will be more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one line in your testbench, I think:

```
    D <= '1';
    RST <= '0';
    wait for 100 ns;

    stopClk <= TRUE;  -- add this line

    wait;
  end process;

END;
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/56Mm

That way, when the test is finished, the clock `stopClk` signal turns off the clock generator and the simulation finishes. It finishes because it reaches a state called *event starvation*. Every time a line of code containing a signal assignment is executed, an event is added to the simulators *event queue* (its "to do list"). If you create a situation where no such lines continue to be executed, then the event queue becomes empty. This is event starvation. The simulator detects that and the simulation stops. (If you think about, what else could it do?)

Without this extra line, the simulation runs forever, because the clock generation process executes signal assignments forever, so the event queue is never empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but: consider using **if rising_edge(CLK)** or maybe **if CLK='1' and CLK'event** instead of **wait until**. Not all synhtesis tools support that kind of code and anyway it's rare to see it in professional world ;)

p.s. **stopClk** signal is not driven (or was it?) Your TB clock is enably by that, yet I guess it remains **'u'** for the whole simulation. Unless forced in the simulation.